# Different verbs in comparing dergee of intent/feeling/etc

Tags: verbs, comparisons, construction

Sometimes people compare degree of something (an intent/feeling/etc) by giving completely unrelated example (by using "same way as" or "like").

Is something like "The boy wants that bicycle like a fish needs water" considered okay?
Or I should always keep same verb: "The boy needs that bicycle like a fish needs water"?

Comment: @YosefBaskin question was is constructions like that acceptable (make sense?). "The boy *wants* that bicycle like a fish *needs* water" (different verbs) or "The boy *needs* that bicycle like a fish *needs* water"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction is better the first way:

> The boy wants that bicycle like a fish needs water.

No parallel is needed more than using the two verbs *wants* and *needs*. Does the boy need the bicycle, or does he want it so much that to him it is life-sustaining?  He wants it, that's all. The fact that a fish truly needs water but the boy does not truly need the bicycle produces the irony. The verbs are parallel in construction -- they do not need to be identical.

To say that "the boy needs that bicycle like a fish needs water" is not accurate, but it is correct English.